# Call to a member function toJson() on null. Voyager User Model

Tags: laravel

При попытке добавить пользователя вылетает эксепш Call to a member function toJson() on null.

/vendor/tcg/voyager/src/Models/User.php

```
  public function setSettingsAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['settings'] = $value->toJson();
    }
```

Voyager: 1.2.3
PHP: 7.2

Comment: у вас `$value` = `null`.. что вообще туда передаёте?

Comment: Я ничего не передавал, сделал dd, действительно null. Вопрос решил, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо добавить в App\User

```
public function setSettingsAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['settings'] = $value ? $value->toJson() : null;
}
```

А класс User наследовать от  \TCG\Voyager\Models\User, затем в http://51.15.58.168:8011/admin/bread/users/edit указать App\User